# Android FirebaseUI: Showing a button even when only one provider is chosen

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

I followed the documentation to use FirebaseUI in my Android application: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/firebaseui - their screenshot shows a bunch of buttons to log-in, one per provider.

I assume that all these buttons are shown because several providers have been used in their sources (*cf.* their part "Sign in"). In my application, only one provider is used and I have no button. Instead, a Google popup is shown in the device, asking the user for connection.

But I would prefer that user clicks on a Google button, and then the popup would be shown.

Is it possible to show this FirebaseUI button (in other words: I don't want to create my own button, customize it to make it feel as the button on the screenshot of the documentation, add click listener on it, etc.)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.setAlwaysShowSignInMethodScreen(true)` must be called